# Soul vs Microtype in regards to Tracking

Tags: typography, microtype, soul

When using small/all caps, I was told to adjust the tracking alongside. I have found `\SetTracking` from `microtype` and `\so` from `soul`. Is there an advantage to using one or the other and if yes why? Do they do exactly the same thing?

Comment: `microtype` operates at the font level, while `soul` does complicated boxing and unboxing. I'd go with the former, if available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's do an experiment with the following input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\scshape\textls{x} % this for not spoiling the test

\tracingcommands=1
\wlog{^^J========================^^J}

\so{Some spaced out text}

\wlog{^^J========================^^J}

\textls{Some spaced out text}

\wlog{^^J========================^^J}
\tracingcommands=0
\end{document}
```

In the log file, the command list for `\so` starts at line 137, ending at line 4694, while the command list for `\textls` starts at line 4698, ending at line 4827. The first `\textls` command is just to avoid corrupting the test with irrelevant commands produced from font initialization.

The difference is that `\so` must do a lot of boxing and unboxing, while `microtype`'s tracking works at the font level. The `\so` command has also to do many checks for allowed tokens and doesn't accept any macro in the text, so it must sometimes be helped with `\soulregister`.

I have no doubt in choosing between executing 4500+ and 129 commands for the same text. ;-)